# Finding all pages on domain with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sitemap, robots.txt

I'm trying to find all the pages on a domain with Node.
I was searching on Stackoverflow, but all i found is this thread for Ruby: [Find all the web pages in a domain and its subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272920/find-all-the-web-pages-in-a-domain-and-its-subdomains) - I have the same question, but for Node.
I've also googled the question, but all I find are scrapers that do not find the links to scrape themselves. I was also searching for something like "sitemap generator", "webpage robot", "automatic scraper", "getting all pages on domain with Node" but it didn't bring any result.

I have a scraper that needs an array of links it will be processing and for example I have a page www.example.com/products/ where I want to find all existing sub-pages, e.g. www.example.com/products/product1.html, www.example.com/products/product2.html etc.

Could you give me a hint how can I implement it in Node?

Comment: Will the existing crawler work? http://www.crawlmysite.in

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Crawler (https://www.npmjs.org/package/crawler). You can use it to crawl the website and save the links.

> Crawler is a web spider written with Nodejs. It gives you the full
>   power of jQuery on the server to parse a big number of pages as they
>   are downloaded, asynchronously. Scraping should be simple and fun!